# How to make a class immutable with Date object in it?

Tags: java, date, immutability

This is just from an academic learning point of view. All I know is that whenever we want to make some class immutable, 
- it has to consist of final primitive fields
- reference does not escapes during construction of object
- if uses other objects, then those objects need to be recursively immutable too or API immutable classes like java.lang.String, among some other detailed lookouts!

But I recently came accross a question wherein an interviewer asked a candidate to create an immutable class that has a java.util.Date in it. My first impression tells that its not possible although we can do workarounds with String containing the date string rather than in Date object itself.

Please clarify me on this. Thank you.

Comment: Fields do not need to be immutable types, they just can't be mutated.

Comment: simple make it(class) final!!!

Comment: And what is your question? Where do you see problems with a field that is of type `Date`? It is up to the programmer if he passes this Date instance to calling class. He is not forced to do so and therefore it is not a problem to have such kind of field.

Comment: @BhargavModi - making a field `final` doesn't prevent the underlying object from being modified.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth make that class final !!!!!

Comment: @BhargavModi: Declaring a class `final` has nothing to do with it being immutable.

Comment: @BhargavModi - No. Making a class *final* prevents other classes from *extending* it. It has got nothing to do with *immutability*.

Comment: @TheLostMind that's why string objects are immutable because the class is too.

Comment: @BhargavModi -  And what about `Class` class?. It is *final* as well. Are the instances *immutable*?.

Comment: @BhargavModi: Please [do some research](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/final.html) before spouting such nonsense...

Comment: @BhargavModi Learn about [immutable objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). That Wikipedia page specifically discusses the [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class in Java.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The simplest thing to do here to make the class immutable is to create a defensive copy of the Date object (when it is passed in the construction parameters). Then don't provide any setters as well. Like this no reference to the Date field in the class is visible to code outside this class and thus the Date can't be modified.

See Tom's comment for required getter characteristic! Thanks for the addition.

(Getter should return a copy of the date field as well, since Date itself is mutable, and changing the returned field from the getter will change the class's field as well.)

For more information and details:
http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=31551&seqNum=2

Comment: And if there needs to be a getter method like `public Date getDate() {}`, then create a copy in there as well: `return new Date(privateDate.getTime());`.

Comment: Answer is perfect with the given link in it... Defensive copy is explained beautifully.

Comment: While implementing stuff, the better option I felt was to use String for formatted date or long variable for epochToDate.

Comment: How can I do this in Kotlin data classes? For normal classes of kotlin same way mentioned in the answer will work?

Comment: @faizan For kotlin data classes i declared the one val i wanted to apply defensive copy to with the annotation "JvmField" in order to stop the kotlin compiler from creating its own setter and getter and then i went forward to declare my own. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 7):

I suggest to create a wrapper class around the date which you are using and dont provide any setters or any method which can actually change the value.

For making it immutable you need to consider following things :

1. You need to make sure that the class cannot be overridden, - make it as final.
2. Make all the fields as private and final.
3. Dont provide any setters or any method which changes the instance variable.
4. Defensively copying the objects between callee and caller.

   Consider [this tutorial](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=15) for more

Comment: Either that, or return a copy of the Date

Comment: Why bother with a wrapper?  Just create a (private) copy, and then *don't* modify it.

Comment: *defensive copies of  *non-primitive mutable fields*.

Answer (score 1):

1) Don’t provide “setter” methods.

2) Make all fields final and private

3) Don’t allow subclasses to override methods - Declare class as final

4) For mutable instance variables - Ex date:  In this case a special attention to be given.

5) Make the constructor private and construct instances in factory methods.
Factory method to store object creation logic in single place.

```
   public static MyImmutableClass createNewInstance(Integer fld1, String fld2, Date date)
{
    return new MyImmutableClass (fld1, fld2, date);
}
```

6) Instead a new Date object, with content copied to it, should be returned.

```
public Date getDateField() {
    return new Date(dateField.getTime());
}
```

- Here dateField is field which is set inside private constructor